# PL/SQL error with transposing string to rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to spilt a string in my table into separate rows and then looking up those values in another table to see which values doesn't exists. This is the code I am using:

```
SELECT NAME, desc, LABEL, trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) AS ID
from table1 T1, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(str_work,' ','</e><e>')||  
'</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x 

where 

    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
           tabl2 T2
        WHERE
           T1.ID = x.ID) AND t1.str_work IS NOT NULL);
```

The code is giving an error:

```
ORA-00904: "X"."ID": invalid identifier
```

I am not able to figure out what the issue is. I would appreciate all your help and suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries002.htm#sthref2213) (emphasis added):

> You can use a column alias, `c_alias`, to label the immediately
>   preceding expression in the select list so that the column is
>   displayed with a new heading. The alias effectively renames the select
>   list item for the duration of the query. **The alias can be used in the
>   `ORDER BY` clause, but not other clauses in the query.**

So you can't refer to the `ID` alias in the subquery. That alias isn't coming from the inline view you've labelled as `x` anyway, though. You could solve both issues, I think, by repeating the `trim` in the subquery:

```
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
           tabl2 T2
        WHERE
           T1.ID = trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')))
    AND t1.str_work IS NOT NULL);
```

But is that supposed to be referring to `T2.ID` - otherwise there is no correlation?

Alternatively you could introduce another inline view to avoid the repetition, but it's probably adding complexity for not much gain here.